# Are multi-character character constants valid in C? Maybe in MS VC?

Tags: c, visual-c++, char

While reviewing some WINAPI code intended to compile in MS Visual C++, I found the following (simplified):

```
char buf[4];

// buf gets filled ...

switch ((buf[0] << 8) + buf[1]) {
    case 'CT':
        /* ... */

    case 'SY':
        /* ... */

    default:
        break;

    }
}
```

Assuming 16 bit chars, I can understand why the shift of `buf[0]` and addition of `buf[1]`. What I don't gather is how the comparisons in the case clauses are intended to work.

I don't have access to Visual C++ and, of course, those yield `multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]` warnings on gcc/MingW.

Comment: Multi-character constants are just `int`s with a fancy representation, e.g. `'ABCD'` is just `0x41424344`.

Comment: [This character literal reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal) should hopefully give you some insight.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks for the link, which is about c++, but led me to http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/character_constant. I'm adding this sites to my bookmark bar :-)

Comment: **About duplicate question mark:**
This one is different in that it actually spells what is asking about. IMO next newbie wondering about multi-character constant validity in C will find this one right away. I certainly couldn't find the other one...

Comment: @PaulR: 1) There is no requirement to use ASCII encoding. 2) The standard does not guarantee endianess 3) All _character constants_ have type `int`, not just multibyte.

Comment: Any reason you assume 16 bit `char`? And you invoke undefined behaviour for character codes >127 and 16 bit `int`.

Comment: @Olaf, I should have written "at least 16 bit chars". I meant to convey that I understood the fact that the shifting + addition was packing 2 (at least 16 bit chars) low bytes into an (at least 16 bit) char. After all the shifting is just 8 bits.

Comment: If you have `char` with 16 bits, you have 16 bit bytes, too! Simply because `char` **is** a "byte"! And the operation is not done as `char`, but `int` or `unsigned int`.

Comment: @olaf then what I don't understand is how the shifting works. If char is 1 byte, wouldn't the shifted 8 bits in `buf[0]` be lost? After all `buf[0]` is not a character constant (int) but a char (1 byte).

Comment: You cannot shift a `char` in C! Read about integer promotions. And again: 1 byte is **not** identical with "8 bits"!

Comment: Thanks @olaf for guiding me in the right direction, albeit so indirectly. Now I've read the _Semantics_ paragraph in 6.5.7 of the standard. So the crux of it is: `buf[0]` is being promoted to `int` in expression `buf[0] << 8` then added to `buf[1]` yielding an `int`value; which in turn is being compared to other `ints` (character constants) in the `case` clauses. Hope i finally got it..

Comment: "albeit so indirectly" - Yes, I try to make ppl think for themselves. The knowlege will be remembered much better that way. Good you did! Just go for what a byte is and what _not (necessarily)_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a non-portable way of storing more than one `char`s in one `int`. Finally, the comparison happens as the `int` values, as usual.

*Note: consider concatenated representation of the ASCII values for each individual `char` as the final `int` value*.

Following the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Character_constants) article, (*emphasis mine*)

> [...] Multi-character constants (e.g. `'xy'`) are valid, although rarely useful — they let one store several characters in an integer (e.g. 4 ASCII characters can fit in a 32-bit integer, 8 in a 64-bit one). **Since the order in which the characters are packed into an int is not specified, portable use of multi-character constants is difficult.**

Related, `C11`, chapter §6.4.4.4/p10

> An integer character constant has type `int`. The value of an integer character constant
>   containing a single character that maps to a single-byte execution character is the
>   numerical value of the representation of the mapped character interpreted as an integer.
>   **The value of an integer character constant containing more than one character (e.g.,
>   `'ab'`), or containing a character or escape sequence that does not map to a single-byte
>   execution character, is implementation-defined.** [....]

Comment: In other words, The value of an integer character constant containing more than one character...is implementation-defined. Which makes `int foo = 'yes';` to be valid

Comment: Thanks to both, now I understand. It's valid bud non-portable, hence gcc's warnings. So if I were to compile this with another compiler I might end comparing the equivalent of CT to TC, depending on how the compiler chooses to store 'CT'.

Comment: There is a portable way, at least with `sizeof(char) < sizeof(int)`: `int i = (char)'3'`. As is to store multiple `char`s in an `int` (with the given constraint): use bitshifts. And _**multibyte** character constants_ **are** `int` (not `char`) like any other _character constant_. Problem is the "packing" in the `int`.

Comment: @Michi Note: a multi-character constant like `int foo = 'yes'` is problematic when `int` is 16-bit`.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they are valid and its type is `int` and its value is implementation dependent.

From [C11 draft, 6.4.4.4p10](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.4p10):

> An integer character constant has type int. The value of an integer
>   character constant containing a single character that maps to a
>   single-byte execution character is the numerical value of the
>   representation of the mapped character interpreted as an integer. **The
>   value of an integer character constant containing more than one
>   character (e.g., 'ab'), or containing a character or escape sequence
>   that does not map to a single-byte execution character, is
>   implementation-defined.**

(emphasis added)

GCC is being cautious, and warns to let you know in case you have used it unintentionally.

Comment: A good compiler will never compile [A code like this](http://ideone.com/Hpr9Qh) Without a warning `warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]`